# Thorpe Chapter 21, Issue with proof presented (Lemma 3)

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
[image]

Towards the end of the proof when Thorpe says

[image]

I can't imagine a possible reason why this would be true. Since our surface can have zero gaussian curvature, our shape operator matrix would obviously not be orthogonal. Similarly, having zero curvature would imply an inverse doesn't exist, so you cant use the normal method of multiplying by $(L^{-1})^T$.

Any help?

Comment: What you quote still contains $3$ equations. I guess you have troubles with the last one, specifically $L(E_1)\times L(E_2)=(\det L)E_1\times E_2$.

Comment: Yeah sorry. That one in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $L(E_1) = a E_1 + b E_2$ and $L(E_2) = c E_1 + d E_2$. Then $L(E_1)\times L(E_2) = (ad-bc) (E_1\times E_2) = (\det L)(E_1\times E_2)$. What else is troubling you?

By the way, I'll comment that since $E_1,E_2$ need not be (a scalar multiple of) an orthonormal basis, we don't know that that the matrix for $L$ with respect to the basis $\{E_1,E_2\}$ is symmetric.

Comment: Nope thats all. Perfect answer, thanks

Comment: Are there any books like Thorpe that you can recommend that don't skip steps like this? I've gone through this book now but I still feel like I've learned so little.

Comment: Louis: Do you have a strong background in multivariable analysis and differential forms? Thorpe's book is a bit heavy on notation, basically doing stuff in graduate-course style. For a bit more naïve treatment, you might check out my text (linked in my profile); I have in there an optional section doing things with moving frames (differential forms), but the text as a whole avoids them. I guess you should be more specific about what you mean by "books like Thorpe" :)

Comment: I had no prior experience in differential forms sadly. But I had a semester of experience in multivariable analysis and a semester of complex analysis, both of which have been my favourite courses so far. 
The differential geometry course at my university didn't require exterior calculus experience for the differential geometry course, but readily used differential forms throughout. I really enjoy the thoroughness of Thorpe, but more often than not he moves a bit too quickly for my liking.

Comment: The standard undergraduate treatment based on differential forms is [O'Neil's book](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Geometry-Revised-Second/dp/0120887355).